# What mean : $p(t,x)$ be the probability density of finding the system in state $x$ at time $t$?

Tags: probability

Let $$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+h(X_t)dW_t,$$ where $X_0=X_0$ an SDE. What mean : $p(t,x)$ be the probability density of finding the system in state $x$ at time $t$ ? If $(X_t)$ is the solution of the SDE, does it mean that $p(x,t)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\mathbb P(X_t=x)$ ? I don't think so since $\mathbb P(X_t=x)=0$. I walso thought to $p(x,t)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\mathbb P(X_t\leq x)$, but this doesn't make sense since $X_t$ won't be in $x$ at time $t$. I would be grateful for help. Here the context :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$p(t,x)$ is the density function of $X_t$. In other words $$\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\}=\int_A p(x,t)\,\mathrm d x.$$